# What is causing this ghostly image of a circuit board to appear in images from my webcam?

Tags: troubleshooting, artifacts, webcam

I am the owner of a Logitech c930e webcam. This morning I turned it on and the images looked like it was a PCB printed on the sensor. So I am here asking to anyone that know something about this phenomenon if it is actually completely unfixable or if I can do something to get the right image again.

[image: broken sensor]

Comment: Does the same pattern appear when the camera is pointed in a different direction?

Comment: Yes, meanwhile I did a little search and it seems that the problem could be due to light coming from the back of the sensor and interfearing. So it might be some internal light sealing doesn't working properly.

Comment: @MatteoRigodanza Welcome to photo.se. It is perfectly valid to post your research result as an answer for others, who might have this problem too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that light may be leaking in behind the sensor.  Look for damage to the casing.  Maybe the cure is a bit of black tape.  I wouldn't think a device of this price is worth more than an ad hoc repair.

Answer (score 5):

I finally solved the problem. I opened up the webcam cause I was curious at that point and a tiny plastic pin dropped out. It could happend since sometimes there are some plastic scratces due to the plastic piercings that were not complitely cleand out. Anyhow I reached the PCB itself where the lens is mounted on the CMOS sensor and I noticed that on the back of the lens mount ther was a tiny hole. So, a little inspection and I understood wath happend. The lens mount consist of 2 screws that keep it align orizzontally and 2 plastic pins inserted in the PCB (just for safety I think). One of those plastic pins was damaged in the production and today it dropped out from his little housing allowing the light to come throught. A little piece of insulating tape on the hole and the 'PCB artifacts' were gone. Thanks everyone for the support!

Here is a photo of the PCB with the missing pin:
[image]

Comment: I've heard of "pin-hole" cameras before, but never like this.